# SSH error: Permission denied, please try again

Tags: server, ssh, login, openssh

I have an Ubuntu server setup using amazon ec2 instance. I need to connect my desktop (which is also a ubuntu machine) to the ubuntu server using SSH.

I have installed open-ssh in ubuntu server. I need all systems of my network to connect the ubuntu server using SSH (no need to connect through pem or pub keys).

Hence opened SSH port 22 for my static IP in security groups (AWS).

My SSHD-CONFIG file is:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Through webmin (Command shell), I have created a new user named 'senthil' and added this new user to 'sudo' group.

```
sudo adduser -y senthil
sudo adduser senthil sudo
```

I tried to login using this new user 'senthil' in 'webmin'. I was able to login successfully.

When I tried to connect ubuntu server from my terminal through SSH,

```
ssh senthil@SERVER_IP
```

It asked me to enter password. After the password entry, it displayed:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

On some research I realized that, I need to monitor my server's auth log for this. I got the following error in my auth log (/var/log/auth.log)

```
Jul  2 09:38:07 ip-192-xx-xx-xxx sshd[3037]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=MY_CLIENT_IP  user=senthil
Jul  2 09:38:09 ip-192-xx-xx-xxx sshd[3037]: Failed password for senthil from MY_CLIENT_IP port 39116 ssh2
```

When I tried to debug using:

```
ssh -v senthil@SERVER_IP


    OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to SERVER_IP [SERVER_IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA {SERVER_HOST_KEY}
debug1: Host 'SERVER_IP' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in {MY-WORKSPACE}/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
senthil@SERVER_IP's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
Permission denied, please try again.
senthil@SERVER_IP's password:
```

For password, I have entered the same value which I normally use for 'ubuntu' user.

Can anyone please guide me where the issue is and suggest some solution for this issue?

Comment: You did set the password for the `ubuntu` user? And you're sure you're typing it correctly? Also include the output of `id ubuntu` run from your server in your question. Did you lock the account perhaps? Consider including the output of `grep ^ubuntu /etc/passwd /etc/shadow` (and change the encrypted password only in the middle of the string).

Comment: Actually I haven't created any seperate user for SSH. I have used the user which I normally use for server login.                                   

The output of grep ^ubuntu /etc/passwd /etc/shadow is:
/etc/passwd:ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash
/etc/shadow:ubuntu:!$6$rWDSGDSGhv$WDFDASGFDAG.Pz0ob54/epaDSGDSGQKnKqQMFG..OieFiLUndF6KnSDGHDSGHmTMjAGHDSH214I7FHSi1:15347:0:99999:7:::

Comment: Thanks again for your clear response.. If I need to create separate user for SSH and add that to some SSH config, can you please give me some steps for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where the issue is and fixed.

I have created a new user (named: senthil) and just used it for SSH. In Ubuntu, I feel that when we create a new user, by default the root user's password will be assigned to the new user. Even then, reset and assign some new password to the newly created users.

Once after the user password reset and making the following changes in sshd_config, now I am able to connect all my systems (from my network) to remote server.

Please Note:
I have switched off all SSH authentications (like RSAAuthentication, PubkeyAuthentication and KerberosAuthentication).. I have turned on only the PasswordAuthentication.

Thank You.

Comment: "I feel that when we create a new user, by default the root user's password will be assigned to the new user." <-- No, you are asked to set a password using `adduser`. Did you use `useradd` instead?

Comment: I have used the following two commands:
"sudo adduser -y senthil" and 
"sudo adduser senthil sudo".

May be as I have created users using webmin commandline, it haven't asked me to enter password during user creation

Comment: gertvdijk, consider that I am having only webmin access for a server. In webmin command line, GUI prompt or the step by step installation is not possible. So I feel that in webmin command line, it haven't asked me to enter password. In such cases what can I do? Is there any other command, other than "sudo adduser -y senthil" such that in ONE COMMAND I will create and assign passwords to users? sorry for the lengthy question.

Comment: But you have console access on an EC2, right? Of course, running these commands via Webmin is VERY limited. Sorry that I wasn't explicit on running this in the console rather than Webmin (this really limits your options/capabilities).

Comment: You meant that, you just change the password of that user and everything OK? I have the same problem. In my case all the users include root get that error?!

Answer (score 15):

You've locked the account.

From the manpage of `usermod(8)`:

```
-L, --lock
           Lock a user's password. This puts a '!' in front of the encrypted password,
           effectively disabling the password.
```

Now look at your `shadow` line:

```
ubuntu:!$6$rWDSG...HSi1:15347:0:99999:7:::
```

Unlock it:

```
usermod -U ubuntu
```

*Important note! If this user is preinstalled on the system it may be locked for  a reason (security  reasons), but I cannot decide that for you since this isn't a regular Ubuntu install apparently.*

---

If the above makes you feel uncomfortable, you could create a separate user:

```
sudo adduser username
```

and answer the questions. You should be able to login just fine. Also make it able to become root (use `sudo`) by adding it to the `sudo` group:

```
sudo adduser username sudo
```

In case you need to switch to the `ubuntu` user on the command line, you'll have to use your elevated privileges, because you can't provide credentials for the same reason as why you can't log in using SSH. Now, log in using SSH as `username`, and run this to become `ubuntu`:

```
sudo su -l ubuntu
```

For security reasons I would not advise to use `root` to log in directly.

Comment: I feel the user 'ubuntu' is locked for security reasons. Or to avoid this confusion, I have also tried to login using my root user account.. I am still getting the same error in terminal and auth.log file.

Comment: You mean the `root` account? That account doesn't have a password and is locked by default. Have you enabled it?

Comment: @Kamal I've updated my answer to include how to do that.

Comment: Thanks gertvdijk. I will try this now. I have also editted my question and updated the output of ssh -v ubuntu@SERVER_IP

Comment: @Alaa: No.. I haven't enabled it. Just tried to login using root.. Currently I am using the user: 'ubuntu' for login (in webmin)

Comment: Thanks gertvdijk for your update. In server, I created a new user named 'senthil' and added this new user to 'sudo' group. After this, I tried to access the server from my desktop using:                         ssh senthil@SERVER_IP.. Still I am getting the same error after my password entry. Can you please help me further.

Comment: @Kamal Please add all additional information **in** your question by editing it. This site is not really fit for step-by-step debugging as this is a Q&A site for succinct questions. As a start, provide the same information as requested earlier on the `ubuntu` account and *how exactly* you created the account. Please note that Webmin may restrict something here and you should create the user using the command line as in my answer.

Comment: Sorry gertvdijk if I am troubling you. I have edited my question and updated all my actions. Can you please suggest me now. Thanks again for your patience and help!

Comment: @gertvdijk Bro I have a similar issue. I think I locked the account/server. Can't login via ssh through sudo user neither with root. Can you please take a look at this post?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377546/unable-to-login-to-root-sudo-user

Answer (score 12):

This is not exact answer for this question. But In my case, there was redundant lines. (there were same line twice)

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

and also

```
AllowUsers otheruser
```

You should add 'root' user to this line or comment this line.

And restart ssh `service sshd restart`

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem and it take for me many hours .

However, i note that it is a **wrong password** because of differrence between keyboard layout of server snd client :

In Server,  i thought that i set password : `WEwd@ds` 
And , i note that `@` is `"` in the server keyboard layout.

So the right password is : `WEwd"ds`

---

Thus, you need to check :

### Server keyboard layout  [vs] Workstation  keyboard layout

Comment: This was it.  My Raspbian system reverts to the GB keyboard at every reboot and I have to go into Preferences->Keyboard and Mouse to reset it to US.  Thanks for having this answer waiting for me to need it January 2018.

Comment: I had the opposite problem - Windows changed my keyboard layout for some reason, and so I was giving the wrong password through my SSH client.

Answer (score 5):

In my case,

**I closed Windows PowerShell**

and try it with **Git Bash**

Now It works fine.

And then I throw PowerShell away.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was as easy as setting

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

to:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Don't forget

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, follow 2 simple steps:

1. Change root password
2. Make changes in `etc/ssh/sshd_config` file

If 1st step works, no need to do 2nd step.

**1st Step explanation:**

In your terminal type, `sudo passwd root`, after changing the password try `ssh root@IP` if it works, great. If it does not. Follow 2nd step.

**2nd Step explanation:**

1. In your terminal type, `sudo gedit etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Scroll to # Authentication:

Before it will be like this:

```
#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
```

Make it to :

```
#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
```

Save it and use ssh restart command `systemctl restart sshd`

Now try `ssh root@IP`

Hope this works.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! SSH root login with password stopped to work after I generated ssh key for the root user. I tried to change sshd_config but it didn't help, only resetting root password did. It's strange...

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you
In your sshd_config file you add this following line in the end of the file:

```
AllowUsers senthil
```

This line will allow your server can connect to user's name: senthil. Another user will be denied.
After that go to your terminal on your sever type this command:

```
ssh senthil@yourhostname
```

Done! Good luck to you
More information you can come here and see.
http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-1204/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this solved the issue: In the server running openssh-server I changed the user (myserverusername) and root (root) password to the one I was previously using:

```
sudo passwd myserverusername
```

and

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then reboot the ssh server daemon:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

It is strange because I dont recall changing passwords

Answer (score 0):

For the desperate, double check your `/etc/hosts` file to make sure you aren't tricking your computer into thinking a certain host name has a different IP than it really.  >.<

Answer (score 0):

Check `sshd` access List for Allowed Users(config file)

1. `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. `AllowUsers`

should not be set, it should be commented out `#` as shown in example below.

```
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
ClientAliveInterval 432000
ClientAliveCountMax 0
#AllowUsers TestUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many answers to this questions. I too faced the problem. My case was my ssh connection were working before then, I changed to windows 10 auto upgraded. Did not work on Ubuntu on my desktop for long.

Not sure what was the problem. I checked \etc\hosts file, sshd_config file everything looked alright. Then I decided to check my antivirus settings - bingo that is the problem!

The putty application was on the denied list. So enabled it... then log in successfully. A big scream!

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by

```
# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find a line starting with  `AllowUsers` and add your username to it like this:

```
AllowUsers scom omar ahmed root
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I got struck,this command gives me temporary solution, since I am using different username for Ubuntu

```
chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error output and in my case the reason was this line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AllowUsers ubuntu root
```

Naturally, this was denying access to everyone except `ubuntu` and `root` users.

The following worked:

1. Adding new user in the list:

   ```
   AllowUsers ubuntu root tempuser1
   ```
2. Restarting the `sshd`:

   ```
   sudo service sshd restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

After implementing everything mentioned above, I finally found that a *server reboot* works for me.

I am assuming this was cache? But it was weird for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

### Fault phenomenon

in my case,

- server using `dropbear`.
- client using `openssh-client`

and the client got this err msg (when connnecting):

> Permission denied, please try again

### Troubleshooting

but it not always the **precise reason**.
I check the `dropber.log`, and found the **Source of the problem**:

> User 'xxx' has invalid shell, rejected

then fixed by `chsh -s /bin/ash xxx`.

---

### Summary:

Maybe the reasons for failure are different,
But this troubleshooting method may have reference significance.

// if server reject, it may tell more detail in server log than in response to client.