# openssh: Permission denied

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am new to ubuntu and just started to configure my first ubuntu server.

The problem is with openssh. I made openssh server using tasksel. Forwarded port 22 on router to Server IP. In the local network all works fine. I can ssh to server from any computer. However when I try to ssh using external IP address I get error message:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: Try [SSH error: Permission denied, please try again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/315377/ssh-error-permission-denied-please-try-again) or [Loggin in ssh server: Permission denied, please try again](http://serverfault.com/questions/288223/loggin-in-ssh-server-permission-denied-please-try-again) on SF.

Comment: Please run the OpenSSH client with the `-v` option and [edit] your answer to include the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm port forwarding which was done is working.

If internal machine is working fine then it will refer local ip of the machine directly to access to machine on the port 22

If external ip couldn't ssh to the machine it could be a problem with port forwarding

Telnet to the your external ip and check whether it connects to your local ip machine.

Comment: also the isp could be actively blocking 22 and 23 (mine is)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable the `Port Forwarding` in your High Speed Modem or Personal Router (if you have one).

Log into the admin portal of your Router/HS Modem by using `http://192.168.2.1` (may be 1.1 or something else as per your network range) and look for `Internet Option`. Setup the rule to forward the port 22 traffic to your local server. This will make sure the traffic will be forwarded to your Ubuntu server even Public IP changes from DHCP pool.

Works for me all the time and hope will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this situation. Problem was in IP address as I am using 4G mobile network and they have strange network politics.