# Allow different users to connect to a ssh server (openSSH)

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, openssh, remote-access

I'm new at this: I'm trying to set up a ssh server on my personal
computer with openSSH. So far, I was able to connect to my server
through my computer and also from a different computer in the same network.

However, I am unable to allow access to different user. I have to
put the personal computer user (Mark) in order to access it (mark@192.X.X.X).
When I try with "test" it says "Permission denied".

Here are the lines I added in the sshd_config file:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
AllowUsers    test    Mark
```

I did try to restart the ssh server after the changes,still not
working.

Is there something I forgot to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you use ? In Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 you do not need to configure anything.

Comment: Each user must have an account on the target system. For `test@192.X.X.X` to succeed, there must be a real account with username `test` on that system. For multiple people to login to a single account is generally a bad idea. For multiple people to share files, look at the various forms of FTP instead of SSH.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378157/226614) solve your problem?
It wouldn't be quite fair to tag this as a dupe, since the causes for the problem could be many.

Comment: thank you user535733 it make sense :)